# Is there another way to stop node-stream-recorder?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using the node-stream-recorder npm package to start an rtsp recording to my local drive - please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-recorder for the example code.

I have the recording working and it will stop ok but only when the setTimeout function expires. I would like to be able to stop the recorder myself.

I cleared the setTimeout function with a clearTimeout() but the recorder.js does not then recognise the rec.stopRecording function is fired. I think this may be something to do with the way the RTSP Recorder class is starts/stops the recording as there is an undefined timer property in the recorder.js of the package?

I was hoping to be able to make this work without having to find another package, so before I go that route, I was hoping someone might be able to educate me as to why I can't seem to get the setTimeout to do what I want.

Ultimately, my code:

```
var rec = new Recorder({
        url: 'rtsp://ipaddress/video.h264',
        timeLimit: 1501000, // time in seconds for each segmented video file
        // timeLimit: 5,
        folder: 'F:\\NERS_Records',
        name: 'cam1',
    })

var autoStopTimout;

switch (recCommand) {
    case "start":
        // Starts Recording
        rec.startRecording();  //calls startRecording in recorder.js
        break;
    case "stop":
        // Stop Recording
        console.log('STOP RECORDING! ');
    
    default:
        break;
} 
 

autoStopTimeout = ResetTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('Stopping Recording');
    rec.stopRecording();
    rec = null;
    console.log('Stopped');
    }, 300000);
```

In my stop case aboved I have tried the following:

```
case "stop":
        // Stop Recording
        console.log('STOP RECORDING! ');
        clearTimeout(autoStopTimeout)
        rec.stopRecording();
        rec = null;

case "stop":
        // Stop Recording
        console.log('STOP RECORDING! ');
        clearTimeout(autoStopTimeout); //autoStopTimeout declared outside of switch
                                       //statement so should be accessible here
        setTimeout(()=>{
        rec.stopRecording();
        rec = null;}, 1000)
```

I have tried some other things but if i'm honest, I have since forgotten.

I am including the recorder.js from the package below, I have changed the getChildProcess, original left commented out in the code.

```
//
//  recorder.js
//  node-rtsp-recorder
//
//  Created by Sahil Chaddha on 24/08/2018.
//

const moment = require('moment')
const childProcess = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')
const FileHandler = require('./fileHandler')

const fh = new FileHandler()

const RTSPRecorder = class {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.config = config
    this.name = config.name
    this.url = config.url
    this.timeLimit = config.timeLimit || 60
    this.folder = config.folder || 'media/'
    this.categoryType = config.type || 'video'
    this.directoryPathFormat = config.directoryPathFormat || 'MMM-Do-YY'
    this.fileNameFormat = config.fileNameFormat || 'YYYY-M-D-h-mm-ss'
    fh.createDirIfNotExists(this.getDirectoryPath())
    fh.createDirIfNotExists(this.getTodayPath())
  }

  getDirectoryPath() {
    return path.join(this.folder, (this.name ? this.name : ''))
  }

  getTodayPath() {
    return path.join(this.getDirectoryPath(), moment().format(this.directoryPathFormat))
  }

  getMediaTypePath() {
    return path.join(this.getTodayPath(), this.categoryType)
  }

  getFilename(folderPath) {
    return path.join(folderPath, moment().format(this.fileNameFormat) + this.getExtenstion())
  }

  getExtenstion() {
    if (this.categoryType === 'audio') {
      return '.avi'
    }
    if (this.categoryType === 'image') {
      return '.jpg'
    }

    return '.mp4'
  }

  getArguments() {
    if (this.categoryType === 'audio') {
      return ['-vn', '-acodec', 'copy']
    }
    if (this.categoryType === 'image') {
      return ['-vframes', '1']
    }
    return ['-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy']
  }

  // getChildProcess(fileName) {
  //   var args = ['-i', this.url]
  //   const mediaArgs = this.getArguments()
  //   mediaArgs.forEach((item) => {
  //     args.push(item)
  //   })
  //   args.push(fileName)
  //   return childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg',
  //     args,
  //     { detached: false, stdio: 'ignore' })
  // }


  getChildProcess(fileName) {
    var args = ['ffmpeg', '-rtsp_transport','tcp','-i', this.url]
    const mediaArgs = this.getArguments()
    mediaArgs.forEach((item) => {
    args.push(item)
    });
    args.push(fileName)
    console.log("args", args.join(' '))
    return childProcess.exec(args.join(' '), function(err, stdout, stderr) {})
    }

  stopRecording() {
    this.disableStreaming = true
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer)
      console.log('cleared this.timer');
      this.timer = null
    }
    if (this.writeStream) {
      console.log('killstream function called');
      this.killStream()
    }
  }

  startRecording() {
    if (!this.url) {
      console.log('URL Not Found.')
      return true
    }
    this.recordStream()
  }

  captureImage(cb) {
    this.writeStream = null
    const folderPath = this.getMediaTypePath()
    fh.createDirIfNotExists(folderPath)
    const fileName = this.getFilename(folderPath)
    this.writeStream = this.getChildProcess(fileName)
    this.writeStream.once('exit', () => {
      if (cb) {
        cb()
      }
    })
  }

  // killStream() {
  //   this.writeStream.kill()
  // }

  killStream() {
    this.writeStream.stdin.write('q')
    console.log('Killstream done');
    }

  recordStream() {
    if (this.categoryType === 'image') {
      return
    }
    const self = this
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }

    if (this.writeStream && this.writeStream.binded) {
      return false
    }

    if (this.writeStream && this.writeStream.connected) {
      this.writeStream.binded = true
      this.writeStream.once('exit', () => {
        self.recordStream()
      })
      this.killStream()
      return false
    }

    this.writeStream = null
    const folderPath = this.getMediaTypePath()
    fh.createDirIfNotExists(folderPath)
    const fileName = this.getFilename(folderPath)
    this.writeStream = this.getChildProcess(fileName)

    this.writeStream.once('exit', () => {
      if (self.disableStreaming) {
        return true
      }
      self.recordStream()
    })
    this.timer = setTimeout(self.killStream.bind(this), this.timeLimit * 1000)
    console.log('Start record ' + fileName)
  }
}

module.exports = RTSPRecorder
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated, and this is my first post so if I haven't followed convention I apologise, please let me know and I'll bear it in mind for the future.

Cheers!